# What Does orthoM() Do Under the Hood?

Tags: android, opengl-es, projection-matrix

I've read the documentation and it says it creates an orthographic projection matrix. However, what does the matrix it uses for calculations look like?

I input values into the method:

```
0, 105.0, 495.0, 190.0, 410.0, 0, 1
```

and it outputs:

```
0.0051282053, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.009090909, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 
-1.5384616, -2.7272727, -1.0, 1.0
```

What would the resulting matrix look like when drawn?

Answer (score 1):

`orthoM` inherits its API from `glOrtho`, which is documented on the relevant man page; based on a quick Googling, [Microsoft's reproduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373965(v=vs.85).aspx) seemed to preserve the proper formatting.

So:

```
2 / (right - left)        0                         0                       tx
0                         2 / (top - bottom)        0                       ty
0                         0                         2 / (far - near)        tz
0                         0                         0                       1
```

... where `tx = - (right + left) / (right - left)`, `ty = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom)` and `tz = - (far + near) / (far - near)`.

The value you've printed is that matrix transposed, because OpenGL is column major.